# How do I select only the required data while analyzing WAVE API results and export it to CSV?

Tags: python, web-scraping, accessibility

I am trying to evaluate the web accessibility of some university websites and carry out an analysis of the data that I gather using the WAVE API in this code that iterates through all the university urls, evlauates them and sends the data back, which is then written to a csv file.

But I don't want the entire data gotten from wave to be in the csv file
Here is the code

```
import csv
import requests

    urls = ["Uni urls"]
    for url in urls:
    response = requests.post('https://wave.webaim.org/api/request?key=G2ARAEHw3232', data={"url":      url, 'reporttype': 3})
    result_id = response.text

    print("result id - ", result_id)

    result_data = response.json()

    with open('wave_test.csv', 'a', newline='') as csvfile:
        fieldnames = ['url', 'total_elements', 'error', 'contrast', 'alert', 'feature',
                      'structure', 'aria', 'alt_null', 'alt_link_missing',
                      'link_suspicious', 'link_empty']

        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        if csvfile.tell() == 0:  # Check if the file is empty
            writer.writeheader()

        # Write the data to a CSV file

     # Extract the data from the result_data JSON
     data = {
        'url': url,
        'total_elements': result_data['statistics']['totalelements'],
        'error': result_data['categories']['error']['count'],
        'contrast': result_data['categories']['contrast']['count'],
        'alert': result_data['categories']['alert']['count'],
        'feature': result_data['categories']['feature']['count'],
        'structure': result_data['categories']['structure']['count'],
        'aria': result_data['categories']['aria']['count']
        'alt_null': result_data['categories']['feature']['items']['alt_null']         ['count'].get('alt_null', {}).get('count', 0),
        'alt_link_missing': result_data['categories']['error']['items']['alt_link_missing']['count'],
        'link_suspicious': result_data['categories']['alert']['items']['link_suspicious']['count'],
        'link_empty': result_data['categories']['error']['items']['link_empty']['count']
    }
   
     for key in data.keys():
         if key in result_data:
             writer.writerow(data)
         else:
             print("key{0} not found in result_data".format(key))
             writer.writerow({'key': key, 'value': 'null'})


#Read the file and print its contents
with open('wave_test.csv', 'r') as file:
    print(file.read())
```

I get errors like

```
'alt_null': result_data['categories']['feature']['items']['alt_null']['count'],
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^
KeyError: 'alt_null' in the context of this code
```

from some of the urls, i used a for loop to iterate through the data dictionary and check if the key is found in the result_data. if it isn't the default value should be null but it is not working and gives me the same error.

I tried using the .get() function here

`'alt_null': result_data['categories']['feature']['items']['alt_null']['count'].get('alt_null', {}).get('count', 0)` 
but it returns this error

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'get'

**How can i add a default value like 'null' to the csv file for data that is missing from the result_data dictionary without the code giving an error?**

Comment: Your question is unclear. Try to highlight what you are asking. You could put specific questions in bold or in their own paragraph.

Comment: okay, thank you very much. I'll do just that